# Make kernel: recipe for target failed

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to get into linux kernels and I found a nice book which I wanted to read. Starting requirement is a readily built kernel which I'm trying to achieve for a few days now. As of now I'm running Debian Squeeze with a 2.6.32-5 kernel which is also the version I'd like to "recompile". The setup is on a VM running Ubuntu as host. I also got enough space left (~21GB).

The last manual I followed is [“Compiling a New Kernel” in the Debian jessie release notes](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/ch08s06.html.en).

So I went to my unzipped kernel package I got from kernel.org and ran

```
make menuconfig #(left the defaults there)
make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=1.0.custom kernel_image
```

This results in this output:

```
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian [new prereqs: ]======
This is kernel package version 13.014+nmu1.
test -d debian             || mkdir debian
test ! -e stamp-building || rm -f stamp-building
install -p -m 755 /usr/share/kernel-package/rules debian/rules
for file in ChangeLog  Control  Control.bin86 config templates.in rules; do                                      \
            cp -f  /usr/share/kernel-package/$file ./debian/;                               \
        done
for dir  in Config docs examples ruleset scripts pkg po;  do                                      \
          cp -af /usr/share/kernel-package/$dir  ./debian/;                                 \
        done
test -f debian/control || sed         -e 's/=V/2.6.32.5/g'  \
                -e 's/=D/1.0.custom/g'         -e 's/=A/amd64/g'  \
    -e 's/=SA//g'  \
    -e 's/=I//g'                    \
    -e 's/=CV/2.6/g'                \
    -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g'             \
    -e 's/=ST/linux/g'      -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'    \
                -e 's/=R//g'    /usr/share/kernel-package/Control > debian/control
test -f debian/changelog ||  sed -e 's/=V/2.6.32.5/g'       \
            -e 's/=D/1.0.custom/g'        -e 's/=A/amd64/g'       \
            -e 's/=ST/linux/g'     -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'         \
            -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g'                            \
             /usr/share/kernel-package/changelog > debian/changelog
chmod 0644 debian/control debian/changelog
test -d ./debian/stamp || mkdir debian/stamp
make -f debian/rules debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf [new prereqs: ]======
make    ARCH=x86_64 \
                    oldconfig;
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
scripts/kconfig/conf -o arch/x86/Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
make    ARCH=x86_64 prepare
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/x86/Kconfig
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  GEN     include/linux/bounds.h
  CC      arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/asm/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
echo done > debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
make -f debian/rules debian/stamp/conf/full-changelog
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/full-changelog [new prereqs: ]======
for file in ChangeLog  Control  Control.bin86 config templates.in rules; do             \
     cp -f  /usr/share/kernel-package/$file ./debian/;          \
done
for dir  in Config docs examples ruleset scripts pkg po;    do              \
   cp -af /usr/share/kernel-package/$dir  ./debian/;                \
done
install -p -m 755 /usr/share/kernel-package/rules debian/rules
sed         -e 's/=V/2.6.32.5/g'  \
                -e 's/=D/1.0.custom/g'         -e 's/=A/amd64/g'  \
    -e 's/=SA//g'  \
    -e 's/=I//g'                    \
    -e 's/=CV/2.6/g'                \
    -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g'             \
    -e 's/=ST/linux/g'      -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'    \
                -e 's/=R//g'  /usr/share/kernel-package/Control > debian/control
sed -e 's/=V/2.6.32.5/g' -e 's/=D/1.0.custom/g'       \
    -e 's/=A/amd64/g' -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g' \
    -e 's/=ST/linux/g'   -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'       \
    /usr/share/kernel-package/changelog > debian/changelog
chmod 0644 debian/control debian/changelog
make -f debian/rules debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
make[2]: 'debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
echo done > debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/vars [new prereqs: ]======

====== making target debian/stamp/build/kernel [new prereqs: vars]======
This is kernel package version 13.014+nmu1.
restore_upstream_debianization
test ! -f scripts/package/builddeb.kpkg-dist || mv -f scripts/package/builddeb.kpkg-dist scripts/package/builddeb
test ! -f scripts/package/Makefile.kpkg-dist || mv -f scripts/package/Makefile.kpkg-dist scripts/package/Makefile
/usr/bin/make    ARCH=x86_64 \
             bzImage
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.h
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/mod/modpost
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/conmakehash
  CC      init/main.o
  CHK     include/linux/compile.h
  UPD     include/linux/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  CC      init/do_mounts.o
  CC      init/do_mounts_initrd.o
  LD      init/mounts.o
  CC      init/initramfs.o
  CC      init/calibrate.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  HOSTCC  usr/gen_init_cpio
  GEN     usr/initramfs_data.cpio
  AS      usr/initramfs_data.o
  LD      usr/built-in.o
  LD      arch/x86/crypto/built-in.o
  AS      arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.o
  CC      arch/x86/ia32/sys_ia32.o
  CC      arch/x86/ia32/ia32_signal.o
  CC      arch/x86/ia32/ipc32.o
  CC      arch/x86/ia32/ia32_aout.o
  CC      arch/x86/ia32/audit.o
  LD      arch/x86/ia32/built-in.o
  CC      arch/x86/kernel/process_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/kernel/signal.o
  AS      arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.o
scripts/Makefile.build:265: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.o' failed
scripts/Makefile.build:365: recipe for target 'arch/x86/kernel' failed
Makefile:878: recipe for target 'arch/x86' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/kernel/linux-2.6.32.5'
debian/ruleset/targets/common.mk:295: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/build/kernel' failed
```

I am experienced in UNIX-usage (been using Linux for some years) but have no clue about kernels so far. Anyone able to help?